# Second pipe operator not working for my regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to learn regular expressions by scraping PDFs, and I seem to be running into an issue when I put a second pipe (`|`) operator in my match object.

I've tried reading various places on the web, but I can't seem to find anything. I am trying to retrieve just the text `Base Attack/Grapple:  +1/–3` in the code below.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"Base\s+Attack/Grapple:\s+(\+|-)\d+/(\+|-)\d+")
match_object = regex.search("flat-footed 14  Base Attack/Grapple:  +1/–3Attack:  Morningstar +2 melee (1d6)")
match_object.group()
```

When I run the code, I get the error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

When I shorten my regex expression to `r"Base\s+Attack/Grapple:\s+(\+|-)\d+/"` it returns `"Base Attack/Grapple:  +1/"`. So it seems to be some issue with using a second pipe operator.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: I am wondering why the second "(\+|-)" part of my regex expression seems to be interfering with me getting ""Base Attack/Grapple: +1/–3".

Comment: As an aside, `[-+]` matches the same strings as `(\+|-)` but is much easier to type. Generally, if you want to match a single character, `[abc]` is preferred over `(a|b|c)` (but beginners often fail to realize that the square brackets always match exactly a single character).

Comment: Okay, thank you tripleee. This will definitely help me write better regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
flat-footed 14  Base Attack/Grapple:  +1/–3Attack:  Morningstar +2 melee (1d6)"
                                         |___ ( an em dash )
```

There is an [`em Dash(–)`](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) in the text you're trying to match, but your regex is looking for [`- hyphen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) so you need to match `– (em dash)`

```
Base\s+Attack/Grapple:\s+(\+|-)\d+/(\+|–)\d+
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yjvUeu/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I would up-vote you, but I'm too much of a noob and don't have any reputation. This is my first Stack Overflow question. 
Edit - I up-voted now, thanks LinPy!

Comment: @DylanAldred welcome to SO enjoy learning and spreading knowledge, no problem mate, always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern: `Base\s+Attack\/Grapple:\s*[\+–\d\/]+`

Explanation of what's added to your pattern:

`[\+–\d\/]+` - match on or more characters present in character class: plus `+`, em dash `–`, digit `\d`, slash `/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjmIPJ/1)